# exponential distribution on waiting bus

Tags: probability

I'm a beginner of probability theory. Here is the question puzzles me.

Suppose the bus station sends bus in every 10 minutes. I have waited 20 minutes without seeing any bus. What is the probability of getting on bus within the next 10 minutes?

$$ P_{exp}(20+0<X<20+10)=\int_{20}^{30}{\frac{1}{10}e^{\frac{1}{10}x}dx}\approx 8.6\%$$
Am I correct? If I link it to "3-doors" problem, the solution suddenly becomes improper. Since the bus must come, so $$P_{real}(X>20+0)=100\%$$, while exponential distribution only gives $$P_{exp}(X>20+0)=e^{-2}\approx 13.5\%$$

Comment: The probability to calculate is not $P(20<X<30)$. It is $P(X<30\mid X>20)$. Also note that $P(X>20\mid X>20)=100\%$ so agrees with what you call the real probability.

Comment: How to calculate P(X<30 | X>20) ?

Comment: By the rule $P(A\mid B)=P(A\cap B)/P(B)$.

Comment: P(X<30|X>20) is P(<30m get bus) given 20m no-bus. P(X<30 and X>20) = P(20<X<30). so $$P(X<30|X>20)=1-e^{-1}=P(X<10)$$ Oh, It's really amazing.